# Open plug-in for Gimp via command-line

Tags: command-line, gimp

I would like to open a plug-in for Gimp (C:\Windows\Program Files\Gimp\bin\gimp- 2.8) via command line. 
The plug-in lies under C:\Windows\Program Files\Gimp\bin\gimp 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins\do.py
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

#### I would like to open a plug-in for Gimp via the command line

> The plug-in lies under `C:\Windows\Program Files\Gimp\bin\gimp 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins\do.py`

This looks like a python script. You can open those with the text editor of your choice:

```
notepad "C:\Windows\Program Files\Gimp\bin\gimp 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins\do.py"
```

Comment: I want to execute it via command line.

Comment: @UliW Then you should make that clear in your question (which says open **not execute**)

Comment: To execute that python script, you've to install python in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want have Gimp execute the plugin when calling Gimp from a command line (or .BAT), you need a "facade" script, because the typical Gimp plugin expects the image to be already loaded, so as a minimum your batch code should load the image before calling the plugin.

I have already answered a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560). You'll find there some sample python code as well as a complete command line invocation.